# Gradle can't reach azure artifacts

Tags: gradle, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I want build android application use Gradle in Azure Devops agent, but my Gradle can't reach  Azure Artifact with error message like this

```
  > Could not resolve com.xx.xxxxxxx:xxxxxxx-gradle:1.0.156.
     > Could not get resource 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/xx/maven/v1/com/xx/xxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy.pom'.
        > Could not GET 'https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/xxx/_packaging/xx/maven/v1/com/xx/xxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy.pom'. Received status code 401 from server: Unauthorized
```

I read many tutorials in stackoverflow and other forum so I found 2 ways and tried but still not working. The 1st way I use Maven Authenticate task and the result is same with above message. The 2nd way I add settings.xml to $HOME/m2/setting.xml and still not working. My settings.xml content is like below

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>xxx</id>
    <username>xxxxxx</username>
    <password>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</password>
  </server>
```

Can you give me a suggestion for my problem? Thank you :)